# How does one deal with $\frac{1}{|x|}$ at zero when multiplying two random variables?

Tags: integration, singularity

To multiply two independent RVs, Wikipedia gives the following approach:

$$f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(z/x)\frac{1}{|x|}dx   $$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution

Maybe I'm just being thick-headed, but doesn't that integral always have a singularity at $0$ due to the factor $1/|x|$, not to mention $f_Y(z/x)$?  Or is it possible this is something like renormalization theory at work, so that

$$\lim_{\delta ->0} \int_{-\infty}^{-\delta}g(x)dx + \int_{-\delta}^\infty g(x)dx$$ where $g(x)$ is the whole function inside the integral,  is well-defined?

Comment: Notice that as $x$ goes to $0$, $z/x$ goes to infinity, and a distribution always goes to zero in the infinite limit.

Comment: @Paul There actually can be some subtle issues with this, for example if $f_Y$ consists of a sequence of triangular spikes of height $1$ and width $2^{1-n},n=1,2,\dots$. In this case you must be more careful because, say, $f_Y(1/x)/x$ will behave quite weirdly on $(0,1)$ (but presumably the singularity there is integrable).

Comment: The set $\{0\}$ has measure zero ... these are density functions after all.  So that integral makes sense as a Lebesgue integral.  If you want a Riemann integral, yes, it could be improper.  These densities are also nonnegative, so "renormalization" will not change the value.

Comment: good point...got stuck in Riemann brain.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an example where $X,Y$ are both Exp(1) variables. Then

$$f_Z(z)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x} e^{-x} e^{-z/x} dx,z>0.$$

(Note that $P(Z=0)=P(X=0 \vee Y=0)=0$.)

You see that the integrand actually has a finite limit at $x=0$ when $z>0$; in effect $f_Y(z/x)$ is serving to remove the singularity by decaying faster than $1/x$ is growing as $x \to 0^+$.

In unusual situations (specifically, when $f_Y(y)=o(1/|y|)$ as $|y| \to \infty$ does not hold), this reasoning can break down, and then the formula is still valid but the singularity is merely integrable rather than removable. One such example would happen with

$$f_Y(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty T(2^{n+1}(x-2n))$$

where $T(x)=\max \{ 1-|x|,0 \}$.

Comment: Yes, I see that with that choice of distribution $e^{\frac{-z}{x}}$ is shrinking faster than 1/x is growing, and suspected that this might save the day even for a Riemann integral.  But can one generalize about what sorts of probability distributions behave this kindly?

Comment: @eSurfsnake Basically you want $f_X(x)=o(1/|x|)$ as $|x| \to \infty$, which can fail in all sorts of weird ways.

Comment: just to be clear, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty1/|x|dx$ is unbounded as  Riemann integral, but falls off that fast...are you also assuming that the function at the heart of this is itself a proper probability distribution, so its integral is 1?

Comment: @eSurfsnake Yes, it should also be a PDF, but note that I wrote a little o.

Comment: got it.  Thanks.